# Can you define readability settings in wp-config.php?

Tags: wp-config

The title basically answers the question, but I am trying to set basically any random setting at will in wp-config.php so that it's not overwritten by default when I do staging -> live database pushes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "no." You can set settings in functions.php or some other system file, but there's not a default setting like database_prefix to do this.